# Excel randomly changes the font

Tags: excel, office365

I have an Excel chart designed with the David font.
Sometimes when I exit the document and reopen it, the font changes to Tohama. The weird thing is that in the box above it says that the font is still set on David.
What could be the reason for this? And how can I fix that?

Comment: So it is only sometimes and it is always changed to Tohama?

Comment: Yes. It is set on David but something it is changed to Tohama (however, it is still written that its set on David)

Comment: Can you check your default font? https://www.mcstech.net/changing-the-default-font-in-excel/

Comment: This question might be better suited for SuperUser, as at StackOverflow we deal with programming questions only. Be sure to check their help page to see the requirements they have for asking questions.

Comment: Pierre44, the default font is set on Body Font.

Comment: Luuklag, alright, I'll check